# Выделение текста цветом в Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

Как в Notepad++ выделить текст, как маркером?
Выделяю Поиск -> Пометить выделенное -> Используя 1-й стиль
Сохраняю изменения. При следующем открытии файла ничего не сохранено.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Собственно это потому, что подсветка нужна только для текущей сессии, она служит лишь визуальным индикатором, чтобы было удобно ориентироваться в том, что на данный момент например ищешь в документе. Не более того. Поэтому все эти подсветки никоим образом не сохраняются ни в какие настройки и прочее.